# Vue.js app doesn't update view as expected

Tags: vue.js

I've bound the input in this tiny app to a computed property called `currentCat` which has both a getter and setter method. Using `console.log` it can been seen that the `cats` array has been property updated, but none of the changes are reflected in the rendered html.

Here is the HTML for the app:

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="cat in cats">{{ cat }}</li>
  </ul>
  <div>{{ currentCat }}</div>
  <input type="text" v-model="currentCat">
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    currentCatIndex: 0,
    cats: ["Bob", "Tom", "Cat", "Dog"]
  },
  computed: {
    currentCat: {
      get() {
        return this.cats[this.currentCatIndex];
      },
      set(value) {
        console.log(value, this.cats[this.currentCatIndex]);
        this.cats[this.currentCatIndex] = value;
        console.log(this.cats[this.currentCatIndex]);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Shouldn't the list and the div in the html update automatically when the computed property's setter runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue can't detect changes to an array when you do:

```
this.cats[this.currentCatIndex] = value;
```

Use one of the followings instead:

```js
this.$set(this.cats, this.currentCatIndex, value)

// or
this.cats.splice(this.currentCatIndex, 1, value)
```

See [list rendering caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).